# Determining pulse shape for Viterbi Equalization

Tags: equalization, viterbi-algorithm

I believe I understand well enough how the Viterbi algorithm can reverse the effects of ISI when the combined impulse response (transmit filter, multipath, receive filter) is known. I've read [How I Learned to Love the Trellis by Bernard Sklar](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~kk/dtsp/tutoriaalit/Sklar_7.pdf), and I also asked about it in a previous question: [Applying Viterbi algorithm to compensate for ISI in PSK31](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/41655/4030).

But how can this technique be applied when the channel distortion isn't known? From my superficial understanding of equalizing algorithms like CMA, they attempt to infer the channel distortion and compensate for it dynamically. My particular interest is HF channels, which would certainly seem to benefit from some dynamic adjustment.

However, in my study of Viterbi equalization so far, I've not found an explanation of how the unknown impulse response of the channel is found. Without that information, the best we can accomplish is to compensate for known elements like the receive and transmit filters. And in a case with no inherent ISI (like RRC filters on each end), then does Viterbi equalization have any value at all?

Comment: you don't need to determine the pulse shape because it is nearly impossible to determine it exactly. Instead you need some statistical model of the noise. See soft input Viterbi http://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/f2010/handouts/lectures/L9.pdf

Comment: I could not be seeing the larger picture, but how is that article about equalization? My concern isn't noise, it's a non-ideal channel response such as multipath.

Comment: Okay, I will state the problematic in another way. "how can this technique be applied when the channel distortion isn't known". If channel distortion is not known deterministicly, you need a probabilistic model. Viterbi equalizer is to find the "most likely" path, and "most likely" means probabilistic. Sorry if my answer still confuses you but it is the best I think I can explain.

Comment: If there's no ISI due to transmit or receive filtering we are trying to remove, and we give up on trying to incorporate multipath into the trellis, and there's no convolutional coding, then what state is there? If the symbols are equiprobable, and the noise is white, what information is there available to build a probabilistic model that's better than decoding symbols based on the sign of the observation? Or in other words, if we observe 0.00001 that may be a 1 with a low probability, what could possibly happen that would make that more likely to be a 0?

Comment: Question 1, I dont understand what you are trying to arrive. Question 2, the PDF of noise which is unknown (white is not distribution). When you are talking about the sign of observation as the "best" strategy, and if we think about "best" in term of maximum likelihood, you are implying that PDF is symmetric with zero mean. Question 3, again symmetric PDF as example, the mean of PDF will ditactate the result to be 0 or 1 for the same observation $x$, i.e. $\mathrm{Pr}(y=0|x=0.00001) > \mathrm{Pr}(y=1|x=0.00001)$.

Comment: Even if the channel is noiseless (but still with some unknown linear transfer function), isn't it still the function of an equalizer to compensate for that undesired distortion? How can a Viterbi equalizer be an equalizer at all if "you don't need to determine the pulse shape" as you wrote? Unless, you are considering multipath ISI as a kind of noise, in which case doesn't "some statistical model of the noise" amount to estimating the response of the channel?

Comment: Okay, sorry if I have used wrong terminologies. To be short, as in my humble knowledge, Viterbi equalizer works on probabilistic model of undesired/unwanted distortion. More information about the model you have, more reliable the equalizer is. You can try to determine pulse shape as you want, but I just dont understand why you need to determine pulse shape if you dont know it a priori. I mean a RX filter must be compliant with the TX pulse shape, at least according to what I have been taught. And the residual ISI exists because of the imperfection of synchronisation, timing etc.

Comment: Your question is "how can this technique be applied when the channel distortion isn't known", right? Can I suppose it is unknown because the imperfection TX-RX is unknown in noiseless system, and because of noise if noise exists? If the distortion is unknown, you need to probabilistic model. If you refuse a model, well, you have 50% chance to be correct in guessing the received bits. Otherwise, no, I don't know the existence of "pulse shape determination for Viterbi equalizer". I believe that there is someone in DSP.SE can tell you about it if it does exist.

Comment: If no ISI, no need for an equalizer. Note that ISI happens because of limited-band characteristic (as you said, eliminated by matched filter, e.g. RRC at both ends) and multipath propagation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersymbol_interference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question with what I've learned in the past 28 days. Hopefully I've got it right!

Viterbi equalization is just one way to equalize the channel, as an alternative to some other method such as convolving the signal with an equalizing filter. Estimating the channel is an entirely separate problem which must be solved independently of the equalization method.

The trouble with an equalizing filter is it compensates for dips in the channel frequency response by amplifying those frequencies. Unavoidably, the noise is also amplified.

There's a tradeoff to be made: the flatter the frequency response is made, the lower the error due to ISI, but the higher the error due to noise. There's an optimal amount of equalization which minimizes the error due to noise and ISI. An equalizer that tries to hit this sweet spot is a minimum mean square error (MMSE) equalizer.

Viterbi equalization offers an alternative solution. The channel estimate will produce an estimated channel impulse response. The coefficients in this impulse response can be used to build the trellis, and the Viterbi algorithm can then find the most likely sequence of transmitted bits, taking into account the estimated distortion from the channel. The receive filter remains a simple matched filter, with no equalization. The Viterbi equalizer is not linear (unlike the equalizing filter alternative), so it's able to compensate for deep spectral nulls in the channel response in a way the equalizing filter can't. The cost is increased complexity.